# No response controls available for password policy violation using spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I have tried retrieving response controls from LdapContext object using spring's ldapTemplate.

```
private <T> T executeWithContext(ContextExecutor<T> ce, DirContext ctx) {
    try {
        if (ctx instanceof LdapContext) {
            LdapContext ldapContext = (LdapContext) ctx;
            ldapContext.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PasswordPolicyControl() });
        }
        return ce.executeWithContext(ctx);
    }
    catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
        PasswordPolicyResponseControl ctrl = PasswordPolicyControlExtractor.extractControl(ctx);
        if (ctrl != null) {
            System.out.println(ctrl.getErrorStatus().getErrorCode());
        }
        throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
    }
    finally {
        closeContext(ctx);
    }
}
```

Below are some points to be noted : 
1. The operation is being performed using admin context.
2. We are using Active Directory
3. I am setting password policy request control before executing the operation.(DirContext is of type LdapContext)

But still I am getting the same message everytime, "LDAP_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION".
There is no mention of which constraint was violated.
I want to retrieve the violated constraint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using admin context is the problem. See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176645/how-to-test-ldap-ppolicy-enforcement/25177513#25177513).