# How to test ldap ppolicy enforcement

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am using openldap 2.4. I have configured it with following configuration.

```
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/HFSchema.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/ppolicy.schema

pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid

modulepath      /usr/lib/ldap
moduleload      back_hdb.la
moduleload      ppolicy.la

database    hdb
suffix      "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw      {SSHA}xzW0DfNFHahvm/C68ZR4YvbZGFQJjfz5

overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_default "cn=DefaultPwdPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com"
ppolicy_use_lockout
ppolicy_hash_cleartext
```

Also I added default password policy

```
# DefaultPwdPolicy, Policies, example.com
dn: cn=DefaultPwdPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=example,dc=com
cn: DefaultPwdPolicy
pwdAttribute: 2.5.4.35
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
objectClass: device
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdMaxAge: 7776000
pwdInHistory: 5
pwdCheckQuality: 2
pwdMinLength: 8
pwdExpireWarning: 432000
pwdLockoutDuration: 900
pwdMaxFailure: 3
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: TRUE
pwdLockout: TRUE
```

But still admin is able to create users without these constraints. How will I confirm if my ppolicy overlay is working? How can I test if these constraint are actually been applied.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The only user that is free from the password policy constraints is the internal `rootdn` user. You shouldn't use that yourself for *anything.* It is the user that `slapd` itself uses to update the DIT. You should define *another* admin user, *in the DIT,* with the necessary permissions. Using the `rootdn` user for admin tasks will bypass every constraint known to man.
2. To use the `ppolicy` fully, you have to use the password policy request control and check for the corresponding response control in your code so you can discover impending expiry, grace periods, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can test password policy with ldap* commands (OpenLDAP LDAP clients), which allow to use LDAP controls.

You must know a valid DN and a password (not rootdn, which override password policy).

For example:

```
clement@ader-xps:~$ ldapwhoami -x -H ldap://localhost -D uid=coudot,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com -W -e ppolicy 
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49); Account locked
```